# installing mysql & phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I just got Amazon EC2 for my website, and installed php, apache etc..

installed mysql with these codes,

```
yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-libs
/sbin/service mysqld start
chkconfig --levels 235 mysqld on
mysqladmin -u root password 'mynewpassword'
```

But, I got this response

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

I installed phpmyadmin, I can't login as root user.

How can I change/set the password?

Comment: Does it not say that you're **not** using a password when trying to connect?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
mysqladmin -u root -p
```

you will be prompted for the password